# Any Print UDF or Print function available in Hive

Tags: hive

Just like SQL, do we have udf or function in hive to print the statement. Is there a way to know what are current queries that are running in back ground in Hive.

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL" -- a language, a specific database management system? What do you mean by "the statement": *the* statement currently running in *your* own session, or *all* statements currently running on the system, or *all* of history? What do you mean by "Hive" -- a CLI fat client runnning on a specific node, or a specific HiveServer2, or all HiveServer2 instances running in parallel, or all of these?

Comment: SQL mean general RDMS. I think we should have just select statement

Comment: Fine - can you list a few "general RDBMS" and how you list the current *(or past)* queries? Can you see a general pattern in that? If yes then you are a much better DBA than I am.